# How to correct this xpath expression

Tags: java, xml, xpath

Im stuck with this problem in java xpath and xml.

```
public class JAXP {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws XPathExpressionException, FileNotFoundException {

        XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath path = factory.newXPath();
        XPathExpression xPathExpression = path.compile("//book[translate(publish_date,'','')>=20050101 and price>=10]/title");

        File xmlDocument = new File("books.xml");
        InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new FileInputStream(xmlDocument));

        Object result = xPathExpression.evaluate(inputSource, XPathConstants.NODESET);

        NodeList nodeList = (NodeList)result;

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            System.out.print("Node name: " + nodeList.item(i).getNodeName());
            System.out.print(" Node value: " + nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
            System.out.print("\n");
        }

    }

}
```

I need to write in output all books with price above 10$ and publish_date after 2005. Is there a problem with my main clas? Any kind of help will be appriciated. Dont judge me im a beginner,learning by myself and this is only place where i can ask for help.

xml is too big sorry for that.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE catalog SYSTEM "books.dtd">
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2002-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk103">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
      <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
      society in England, the young survivors lay the 
      foundation for a new society.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk104">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Oberon's Legacy</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-03-10</publish_date>
      <description>In post-apocalypse England, the mysterious 
      agent known only as Oberon helps to create a new life 
      for the inhabitants of London. Sequel to Maeve 
      Ascendant.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk105">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>The Sundered Grail</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-09-10</publish_date>
      <description>The two daughters of Maeve, half-sisters, 
      battle one another for control of England. Sequel to 
      Oberon's Legacy.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk106">
      <author>Randall, Cynthia</author>
      <title>Lover Birds</title>
      <genre>Romance</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2003-09-02</publish_date>
      <description>When Carla meets Paul at an ornithology 
      conference, tempers fly as feathers get ruffled.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk107">
      <author>Thurman, Paula</author>
      <title>Splish Splash</title>
      <genre>Romance</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2004-11-02</publish_date>
      <description>A deep sea diver finds true love twenty 
      thousand leagues beneath the sea.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk108">
      <author>Knorr, Stefan</author>
      <title>Creepy Crawlies</title>
      <genre>Horror</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2005-12-06</publish_date>
      <description>An anthology of horror stories about roaches,
      centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk109">
      <author>Kress, Peter</author>
      <title>Paradox Lost</title>
      <genre>Science Fiction</genre>
      <price>6.95</price>
      <publish_date>2006-11-02</publish_date>
      <description>After an inadvertant trip through a Heisenberg
      Uncertainty Device, James Salway discovers the problems 
      of being quantum.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk110">
      <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
      <title>Microsoft .NET: The Programming Bible</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>36.95</price>
      <publish_date>2006-12-09</publish_date>
      <description>Microsoft's .NET initiative is explored in 
      detail in this deep programmer's reference.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk111">
      <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
      <title>MSXML3: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>36.95</price>
      <publish_date>2007-12-01</publish_date>
      <description>The Microsoft MSXML3 parser is covered in 
      detail, with attention to XML DOM interfaces, XSLT processing, 
      SAX and more.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk112">
      <author>Galos, Mike</author>
      <title>Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>49.95</price>
      <publish_date>2008-04-16</publish_date>
      <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,
      looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are 
      integrated into a comprehensive development 
      environment.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

Comment: I don't know how you expect us to help you with an XPath expression when you don't show any XML.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Note: This is not a normal forum like you might know it. Please read and follow the guides [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to write a [mcve] and follow their recommendations. This is important so people can help you. You can [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: Please, Post input structure as well.

Comment: im sorry can u tell me what is input structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While checking publish date you are comparing string to digit, 1st typecast your translated date as number then compare it:

Use this XPath hope it will help you.

```
//book[number(translate(publish_date,'-','')) >= 20050101 and price >= 10]/title
```